# Is it possible to move window out of the screen border?

Tags: ubuntu, wmctrl

So I'm currently moving application Windows with `wmctrl` but I can't move a window outside the screen's border. Not talking about moving outside top left corner which we can't even acheive it by mouse, I can't even move most of the window outside the bottom right border.

So I'm wondering is there any way to achieve it? Or is there other terminal tools that can achieve this?

Comment: Works for me on Xfwm4 (Xfce, Debian). If I use something like `wmctrl -r "title" -e 0,5000,5000,-1,-1` I can only see a small rectangle of the upper left corner of the  window which is about the size of the window icon. My resolution is of course much smaller.

Comment: Oh, I'm using Ubuntu and what I got from running command above, it pushes the window to the bottom right corner but it can't push a screen out of the border.

Comment: Yes, I also couldn't get it "out of" the screen. But I guess that's handled by the window manager.

Comment: Oh I see, my goal is to really get to exact coordinate of what I said. So if I set to (5000,5000) I want to move the window to really that coordinate not just push the window's bottom right corner to my screen's bottom right corner. Or at least I want to make it disappear from the screen without minimizing it.

Comment: @Andrew.Wolphoe Did you find a solution? I'm having the exact same issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you hold the very edge of the window with `Alt + cursor` you can drag it to where you won't be able to drag it back. I'm not sure if it's actually "off screen" but you won't be able to get it back with the cursor.

Comment: I mean to drag it off screen through terminal commands not through cursor. For off screen I mean the apicatioj window has some part or whole part that isn't inside the screen border (commonly that 1920x1080 rectangle).